# Export to pdf with same bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created one form with bootstrap. Now i want to export the form to pdf with the same style. please help me to solve out this issue

Here is the file [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckgaed50/)

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 center">

<h3>Fill Your Form</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
First Name:
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
Middle Name:
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
Last Name:
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">


<button id="button" class=" btn btn-danger">Generate PDF</button>
</div>
</div>
```

PDF Result want to be like this

[image: PDF Result want to be like this]

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355775/how-to-generate-pdf-from-html-with-css-bootstrap-classes) , I am not sure if you want to generate pdf without any library.

Comment: i am not using PHP

Comment: @ShanuShaji there is no based ".downloadAndExportMyCoolStyledFormToPdf(html);